# Detect a specific value in multiple records of a selection using the IF clause

Tags: mysql

I want to create a new table from the following table, where it will be presented whether each person has the value '6' at Field_B at any row and null values at Field_C at any row

```
Person_1  Field_B   Field_C
Mike    6   afdafafa
Mike    6   sadasd
Mike    6   afvzv
Mike    6   
John    1   afvzv
John    2   afvzv
John    3   afvzv
John    6   afvzv
John    5   afvzv
John    6   afvzv
John    6   afvzv
Jim     6   
Jim     6   
Jim     6   
Jim     6   
Tom     1   afvzv
Tom     3   afvzv
Tom     4   afvzv
Tom     5   
Tom     3
```

My code is that

```
select Name,
if(TEST1.field_A in ('6')   ,1 ,0)              as 'exists Field_A'
,   if(TEST1.field_B is null    ,1 ,0)              as 'exists Field_B'
from users.sk_test_1 TEST1
Group by Name
```

and I get results like that

```
Jim     1   0
John    0   0
Mike    1   0
Tom     0   0
```

whereas I need something like that

```
Mike 1, 1 (6 exists, null values)
John 1, 0 (6 exists, not null values)
Jim  1, 1 (6 exists, null values)
Tom  0, 1 (6 does not exists, null values)
```

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an illegal grouping, and returning random results for your unaggregate ungrouped fields.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

try a normal grouping

```
select Name,
max(if(TEST1.field_A in ('6')   ,1 ,0))              as 'exists Field_A'
,   max(if(TEST1.field_B is null    ,1 ,0))              as 'exists Field_B'
from users.sk_test_1 TEST1
Group by Name
```